# How to handle versioning of install4j project files

Tags: install4j

We have our code committed to bit bucket where we are able to handle versioning of scripts and files used in install4j project but we are not able to handle versioning of install4j project XML files due to overriding behavior,
we have to do manual merging every time before code commit.
Is there's any way to handle versioning of install4j project XML files or avoid manual merging of changes done by all team members.

Comment: How would you propose to avoid merging changes done by several developers concurrently?

Comment: I am not getting what you are trying to say.

Comment: I did not understand what you are asking. If there are several changes made concurrently to the same file, they have to be merged. If an automatic merge of the VCS fails, they have to be merged manually. I don't see any way around this.

Comment: What we need to do in manually make changes of each team member to project files and commit, but instead of that can we compare respective XML files and make respective changes to those XML's will it work ?

Comment: Yes, you can modify the XML files directly. There is no need to use the install4j IDE.